# Why SELECT "099anystring" = 99 returns true in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Yesterday I ran a query

```
UPDATE table SET col='newvalue' WHERE col = 99
```

where `col` is a VARCHAR

It updated rows like "099string" and "99something" which obviously resulted in wrong updates

I expected to update only where col = "99"

I am using `10.2.40-MariaDB-1:10.2.40+maria~bionic-log`

PS: I know "099anystring" = "99" will work as I intend.

But that is not my question.

My question is what is the technical reason for "099anystring" = 99 returning true?

Comment: Would col = "99" work?

Comment: @DownloadPizza that would work, I didnt try, but my question stays same, what is the technical reason for "099anystring" = 99 returning true?

Comment: Questions asking "why" rarely get useful answers on this level because you're really looking for one of the few people that was in on the design meeting or whatever they used to decide on this to tell you why they decided what they decided. At most, usually, you get documentation telling you that it *is* like this, but very rarely *why* it was chosen. I can see from the documentation that it is done, but it doesn't say why this is so: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html (search for '1a').

Comment: In this case, Alexandre has provided you with an answer saying why the comparison yields true, but I now assume your real question is why converting that string to a number actually just cuts off the non-number part, or something similar. I also assume this particular "why" is going to be harder to find the reason for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're comparing an integer with a string, it casts the string as an integer.

`"099anystring" = 99` is the same as if you're writing `099 = 99` which in both cases return true

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/equal/

Comment: I guess this will just prompt a follow up question or an edit to the original question here, why is converting `'099anystring'` to a number yielding `99`, and not an error or not-a-number or whatnot.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen must be by design, as to *why* is this by design, that gets out of my field of expertise heh :)